# In Blazor WebAssembly in a component, how can I make DateTime.ToString use the date format of the current culture, assuming the culture is correct?

Tags: c#, datetime, localization, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have temporarily set my browser language and locale to English - United Kingdom even though I am in the United States.  I have removed "en-US" and now have "en-GB" as my only language preference.

In my Blazor WebAssembly site, on a component, I have a property that returns a string: `myDate.ToString("d") + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DisplayName;` that renders on my page as `6/27/2020en (GB)`, where myDate is a DateTime set to June 27, 2020 at 00:00:00.000.  My Blazor site has `app.UseRequestLocalization(...)` middleware set up.

Isn't is supposed to show the date in UK format, namely `27/06/2020`? I can only guess that ShortDatePattern isn't getting properly set from CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.  What could it be?

UPDATE: All WebAssembly component outputs show me that `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern == "M/d/yyyy"` even though `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name == "en-GB"`.  Why might that be?  What sets ShortDatePattern from the culture and can I "re-initialize" it?

An explicit call to `myDate.ToString("d", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"));` still strangely outputs the **M/d/yyyy** format (U.S. format). **Why might that be?**

UPDATE 2:  I created a minimal example: File-New Project, Blazor Web Assembly, .NET 5 ASP.NET Core hosted.  I replaced App.Razor with the following:

```
<div> current culture @(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name) </div>
<div> current date format @(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern) </div>
<div> today @DateTime.Now.ToString("d") </div>
```

That results in (unexpectedly):

[image]

Firefox browser settings (Edge and Chrome are similar and show the same issue):

[image]

That results in sending `Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3`--which seems to be the correct way to "prefer en-GB" and results in CultureInfo.CurrentCulture having the correct value.

I've tried it with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.* nuget packages version 5.0.9, 5.0.11 - both show the same incorrect result.

UPDATE 3: The same minimal project in 6.0.0-rc.1 works and gives the right date format!  **Is this really a Blazor 5 bug that they never fixed?**

Comment: maybe `27/06/2020` which would be UK date format

Comment: In that case you might want to do `myDate.ToString("d", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"))`  see: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PICkP3

Comment: I want to show the date in the user's format, not specify their format for them. But thanks anyway. :)

Comment: did you tried to use [localization middleware ?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#localization-middleware)

Comment: Ah, now I get it ... So, you're saying that Brwoser language is en-GB, so CurrentCulture _should_ be en-GB, which in turn should lead to myDate.ToString("d") to use "en-GB" _by default_ as the culture, right? But it doesn't. It _is_ using what seems to be en-US , right?

Comment: Yes, exactly, Fildor.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot add comments. Have you checked your web.config? If it's set to "auto" it will use the client's culture and you may see different outcomes.

Comment: @Selvin, I tried `app.UseRequestLocalization();` and `app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions().SetDefaultCulture("en-GB"));`, neither made any difference.  Also, since `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DisplayName` appears correctly, I am guessing that ToString("d") gets culture from somewhere else?

Comment: I tried with `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB")` in regular console app (.NET 5), and `DateTime.ToString("d")` seems to output correct value ("12/10/2021" for today).

Comment: @Evk Couldn't reproduce in dotnetfiddle, neither. Either blazor webassembly is doing something very differently or ... I don't know. Very weird to me.

Comment: And what if you inspect `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo`? Because that's what is actually used, maybe it's somehow different from the current culture.

Comment: Just tried specifying a hard-coded culture as an investigation step: An explicit call to `myDate.ToString("d", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"));` still outputs the M/d/yyyy format (U.S. format). Why might that be?

Comment: Which Browser(s) and which .net version?  With .net6 (preview) it "just works", out of the box.

Comment: I tried it with Firefox, Chrome, and Edge, with .NET 5.

Comment: (all show the same problem)

Comment: `app.UseRequestLocalization()` is middleware, that only applies to Blazor server...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For .NET 6+, this seems to be fixed.

For .NET 5, I could not find the root cause, so I needed to code this workaround, which needs to be called explicitly when needed. Obviously this is undesirable if we can find a better solution to allow the use of DateTime.ToString as intended.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Returns a short date-only string from a date/time value, based on the user's current culture.
/// </summary>
public static string ToLocalShortDate(this DateTime value)
{
    // this is needed because I can't get localization to work -- see https://stackoverflow.com/q/69542125/7453
    //   (if we can fix, better to use DateTime.ToString("d"))

    string format;
    // countries taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country
    if (CurrentCulture.Name.EndsWithAny("US", "CA", "ZA", "KE", "GH", "en"))
        format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    else if (CurrentCulture.Name.EndsWithAny("CN", "JP", "KR", "KP", "TW", "HU", "MN", "LT", "BT"))
        format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    else format = "dd/MM/yyyy";

    return value.ToString(format);
}
        
/// <summary>
/// Returns true if and only if a string ends with any of some strings.
/// The value will not match a null reference.
/// </summary>
public static bool EndsWithAny(this string value, params string[] allowedValues) =>
    allowedValues != null && value != null && allowedValues.Any(s => CurrentCulture.Name.EndsWith(s));
```